# SOLR version 4.4 for Magento Enterprise version 1.12.0.2?

Tags: solr

Does anyone know where I can get SOLR patch for SOLR version 4.4 for Magento Enterprise version 1.12.0.2?

I tried to find the MagentoCommerce.com support system, but there no longer seems to be a support ticket system there.

Thanks in advance and apologies for placing a boring question here!

Answer (score 2):

Solr 3.6.0 is the latest supported version for Magento EE 1.10+.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/solr-ee-faq#upgrade

The support portal is still available in the My Account section of your MagentoCommerce account:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/supportme/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had to log in using our clients login details.

Once that happened, I raised a support ticket in the usual way and now have the patch.

Incidentally, EE 1.12+ only supports SOLR 3.6 for now for those reading this question.

Comment: Glad to hear you could log in. I'm glad to help - 3.6 is the last version supported in nearly all of the EE versions IIRC.